# BOM explosion with HIERARCHY function in HANA

Tags: sql, abap, hierarchy, hana

We're attempting to use the HIERARCHY function in HANA to speed up the BOM explosion process that is currently being done in ABAP. The base query works, but we're trying to refine it more for the end-user. The goal is we want to normalize the assemblies and display a grandparent-parent-child relationship in the output so that every root node will display all sub-components below it before moving on to the next assembly in the output. 
This is my first post here, so if I need to add any code or further clarify I'd be happy to.

**Current output**
[image: Current output]

**Desired output**
[image: Desired output]

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "BOM_EXPLOSION" ("HIERARCHY_TREE_SIZE" NVARCHAR(10),
     "PARENT_ID" NVARCHAR(15),
     "NODE_ID" NVARCHAR(15),
     "QUANTITY" NVARCHAR(10),
     "VALID_FROM" NVARCHAR(10),
     "VALID_TO" NVARCHAR(10)) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE  

insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('6','X-000-XXX-01','Y-000-XXX-S1','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S1','COMP1','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S1','COMP2','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S1','COMP3','2','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S1','COMP4','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S1','COMP5','2','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('4','X-000-XXX-01','Y-000-XXX-S2','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S2','COMP1','2','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S2','COMP2','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','Y-000-XXX-S2','COMP3','1','20171221','99991231');
insert into "BOM_EXPLOSION" values('1','X-000-XXX-01','COMP4','1','20170530','20171221');
```

Comment: Please provide the data that should be used as text, ideally with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` commands. That way we can actually work with it.

Comment: So what are you struggling with? I see no notable differences between current and desired. You don't know how to add top level?

Comment: @LarsBr. Added code per your request. Thanks!

Comment: I got to agree with Suncatcher ... what's the difference between the outputs? What is the actual question?

Comment: In current format, 

Parent ID – Assembly 

Node ID - Components under assembly. 

X-000-XXX-01 is top level assembly which has another sub-assembly Y-000-XXX-S1. We are able use to Hierarchy function exploding BOM. Our requirement is to have “top level assembly” as separated and repeat it for all sub-assemblies below. For e.g. Y-0000-XXX-S1 has “5” components under it and they all belong indirectly to “Top_LEVEL”.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the Root node in your Hierarchy.
I'd recommend reading the Hierarchy functions in HANA:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/4f9859d273254e04af6ab3e9ea3af286/2.0.04/en-US/a93c356d32ef4e7fbd6143b554278eab.html

Specifically for your need, look at the "Root" example in this link:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/4f9859d273254e04af6ab3e9ea3af286/2.0.04/en-US/83cf843bfe3c4fd8a5d2aa828fb383c5.html

It's basically a self join on the hierarchy_root_rank attribute with the node actual rank.